# Read file located at android/app/sample.properties file in android programmatically

Tags: android, google-fabric

I would like to access `.properties` file located at `android/app/` programmatically. Following is my directory structure:

[image]

As you can see in above screenshot when we install fabric it reads fabric.properties file from **android/app/** directory. How fabric is reading that file?  I am not able to get how to read sample.properties file from location described in above screenshot.

I tried following code which returns path **/data/user/0/com.abc**

```
PackageManager m = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        String s = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        try {
            PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
            s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
            Log.i("Register", s);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("Register", "Error Package name not found ", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to keep that file inside assets (`app/src/main/assets/`) directory  and access that using below code:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.properties");
String newPath = path.toString();
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, issue in storing file in assets is it's easily available when someone do reverse engineering and file will be visible under assets folder.